Destructuring Default Parameters
In some example code I am analyzing, I noticed a function syntax I'm unfamiliar with:
function functionName ({} = {}) {}

Here is how it behaves:
function weird ({
    a = 6,
    b = 3
} = {}) {
    console.log(a + b + 'why is this');
}
weird();

This outputs '9why is this' in the console. The variables a, b are not declared anywhere else (this is self-contained code). In fact, attempting to insert 'var' before either argument throws an 'unexpected identifier' error.
What is the meaning of the syntax used to pass in the arguments?
Additionally (/probably part of the answer), why does following modification to the previous code causes an error:
function weird ({
    a = 6,
    b = 3
}) {
    console.log(a + b + 'why is this');
}
weird();

Above I removed the equality to the empty object in the argument portion of the function. Now an error is thrown that a/b are 'undefined'. (The same 'unexpected identifier' error is thrown if you attempt to declare the arguments (using var, const, let, etc).)
This question is about a particularly tricky combination of destructuring and default parameters - unlike another post on destructuring alone.

It's argument destructuring combined with default value syntax.

for future noobies, note that the empty object is only invoked if all of the internal variables are missing - an 'undefined' error will be thrown if only some are present.

mdn example on exactly this

The syntax allows declaring default values for each prop of an object argument. I suggest you play with any syntax you find tricky. The = {} part defaults the argument to an empty object, as undefined can't be destructured.

In more detail, the function will try to read properties a and b from whatever you pass as the first argument and, if not populated, each is defaulted to its declared value. When the argument is undefined it's defaulted to {}, so reading its props won't error. The only expression I can think of that will error is null.

@tao thanks for the response! wish the question would open up so you could leave an answer. the 'error' i came across described in the comment above was passing something like weird({ a: 1, b }); i see now that is improper in a different way

discussion of use cases
